# Append div to the respect li on click

Tags: jquery

I want to show and append a div by clicking an unordered list which is invisible initially.

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
</ul> 
<div class="content" style="display:none;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    $(".content").appendTo("ul > li").css({"display":"block"});
});
```

**The Problem**
When I am clicking on the "li" two content div are showing under the "li" respectively. I want to show the div accordingly that means when the first "li" will be clicked the div will open below it and when the 2nd "li" will be clicked the div will open.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text appended to the respective `li` that is clicked, use `.appendTo(this)`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/un7j4918/)

```
$("ul li").on('click', function () {
    $(".content").appendTo(this).css({
        "display": "block"
    });
});
```

Rather than setting the `display` to `block`, you could swap that out for the `.show()` method:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nadtsqu/)

```
$("ul li").on('click', function () {
    $(".content").appendTo(this).show();
});
```